# Changing Typeface of Justified TextView

Tags: android, layout, textview

I want to use justified text format in `TextView`, so I created `class JustifiedTextView extends WebView`.

But I can't set an external `Typeface`.

I tried `setTypeface` in my code, it doesn't give any error but `Typeface` is not set in `TextView`.

Any changes related to `Typeface` in my class?

**.XML**

```
<com.example.Model.JustifiedTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:id="@id/article_decription" />
```

**JustifiedTextView.Java**

```
public class JustifiedTextView extends WebView {

    private String core = "<html><body style='text-align:justify;color:rgba(%s);font-size:%dpx;margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;'>%s</body></html>";
    private String textColor = "0,0,0,255";
    private String text = "";

    String fontBody = "fonts/AvenirLTStd-Book.otf";

    Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), fontBody);
    private int textSize = 18;
    private int backgroundColor = Color.TRANSPARENT;
    public JustifiedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        this.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        });
    }

    public void setText(String s) {
        this.text = s;
        // this.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        reloadData();
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void reloadData() {
        // loadData(...) has a bug showing utf-8 correctly. That's why we need
        // to set it first.
        // this.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");

        this.loadData(String.format(core, textColor, textSize, text, typeFace), "text/html", "utf-8");
        // set WebView's background color *after* data was loaded.
        super.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
        // Hardware rendering breaks background color to work as expected.
        // Need to use software renderer in that case.
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
            this.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }

    public void setTextColor(int hex) {
        String h = Integer.toHexString(hex);
        int a = Integer.parseInt(h.substring(0, 2), 16);
        int r = Integer.parseInt(h.substring(2, 4), 16);
        int g = Integer.parseInt(h.substring(4, 6), 16);
        int b = Integer.parseInt(h.substring(6, 8), 16);
        textColor = String.format("%d,%d,%d,%d", r, g, b, a);
        reloadData();
    }

    public void setBackgroundColor(int hex) {
        backgroundColor = hex;
        reloadData();
    }

    public void setTextSize(int textSize) {
        this.textSize = textSize;
        reloadData();
    }

    public void setTypeFace(Typeface typeFace){
        this.typeFace=typeFace;
        reloadData();
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.Java**

```
Typeface typeFontBody = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontBody);
JustifiedTextView Description;
Description = (JustifiedTextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.article_decription);
Description.setTypeFace(typeFontBody);
Description.setText("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book");
```

Comment: there is a library for justifiying textview Use it may that can help
I don't have the link but this gradle line for that library
`compile 'com.github.bluejamesbond:textjustify-android:2.1.1'`

Comment: @VivekMishra did you properly set `fonts` directory

Comment: Yes my code works perfectly with that library

Comment: #Viveka Patel  `public class JustifiedTextView extends TextView`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya why are you asking from me ask from who has posted the question

Comment: @VivekMishra Be cool .  Actually `same` type name creates problem

Comment: @VivekMishra Thank you so much....my problem has been solved.This is the [Library Link](https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android/blob/master/sample/src/main/res/layout/test_xml_activity.xml)

Comment: mark comment as helpful as you have posted your own answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android Text Full Jusiftication / Wrapping / Justify / Hyphenate - V2.0 https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android

build.grade

```
dependencies {

    compile 'com.github.bluejamesbond:textjustify-android:2.1.1'
}
```

.XML

```
 <com.bluejamesbond.text.DocumentView xmlns:ext="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                         ext:documentView_antialias="true"
                                         ext:documentView_cacheConfig="auto_quality"
                                         ext:documentView_hyphen="-"
                                         ext:documentView_insetPadding="10dp"
                                         ext:documentView_insetPaddingBottom="10dp"
                                         ext:documentView_insetPaddingLeft="10dp"
                                         ext:documentView_insetPaddingRight="10dp"
                                         ext:documentView_insetPaddingTop="10dp"
                                         ext:documentView_lineHeightMultiplier="2.0"
                                         ext:documentView_maxLines="100"
                                         ext:documentView_offsetX="10dp"
                                         ext:documentView_offsetY="10dp"
                                         ext:documentView_progressBar="@id/progressBarXml"
                                         ext:documentView_reverse="false"
                                         ext:documentView_text="@string/xml_test_data"
                                         ext:documentView_textAlignment="justified"
                                         ext:documentView_textColor="@android:color/white"
                                         ext:documentView_textFormat="plain"
                                         ext:documentView_textSize="12sp"
                                         ext:documentView_textStyle="bold|strikeThru|underline"
                                         ext:documentView_textSubPixel="true"
                                         ext:documentView_textTypefacePath="fonts/helvetica.ttf"
                                         ext:documentView_wordSpacingMultiplier="5.0"/>
```

MainActivity.Java

```
DocumentView Description;
Description = (DocumentView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.article_decription);
Description.setText("TEXT");
```

Comment: @PiyushGupta Yes! Its Done!!